# Verificar valor textbox x mysql (universal app win 10)

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp

Tenho uma textbox onde guardo um valor. Gostaria de saber se esse valor é o mesmo do ultimo id na tabela do meu banco mysql. Como faço isso?

Comment: é recomendado que você forneça detalhes do seu problema como qual cenário o que deseja, e um a parte do teu código para podermos entender e poder ajudar!

Comment: Pergunta editada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi bem, mas começa por aqui:

```
"SELECT coluna1 FROM tabela WHERE coluna1 = LAST_INSERT_ID();"
```

e compara com o valor da TextBox.

Se não for isso, detalha melhor, ok?